# GnuCash how to do laptop purchase payment plan

Tags: gnucash

I bought a laptop for $1000 online and paid by credit card. The payment plan is 10-month payment with 0% interest rate. So it charges $100 to my credit card each month. In this case, how do I do it on GnuCash? Split transaction has to be happen on the same day, where I need the $100 credit card bill split to 10 months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction is not split. You transferred $1000 from your credit card to your fixed asset in one go, nothing split there. Repayment of your credit card liability is a series of entirely separate and unrelated transactions between your checking account and your credit card account.

Answer (score 1):

The initial purchase of the laptop represents a liability to make a series of repayments in the future.  You should therefore credit your `Liabilities:Laptop Purchase` account by $1000 and debit your `Assets:Laptop` account by $1000 when you take delivery of the laptop.

*(Note: depending upon the accounting policies in place in your home or business, it may be legitimate to treat the laptop as a one-off expense instead of an asset with lasting value.)*

Each month when the financing arrangement charges $100 to your credit card, you should show a credit of $100 to `Liabilities:Credit Card` and a debit of $100 to the `Liabilities:Laptop Purchase` account.  As a similar transaction will occur 10 months in a row, there's good reason to set that up as a *Scheduled Transaction*.

Your monthly credit card bill will include the $100 charge along with all of your other credit purchases.  You pay off some or all of this bill as normal.

Comment: That's the correct way to handle this situation, but don't forget to depreciate the laptop in 4 years or so if considering it as an asset. There are relatively few assets that should not be depreciated. A laptop certainly needs quick depreciation. Some people nowadays should think a house should not be depreciated. I disagree...